# How to load an extension in a cefsharp WPF project?

Tags: wpf, google-chrome-extension, cefsharp

I'm trying to load an extension in cefsharp embedded browser in a WPF project. But application freezes while doing so. Here is the code I have been doing to load a very simple extension:

```
    var setting = new CefSettings();
    setting.RegisterExtension(
            new V8Extension(
                "test",
                "document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"));
    Cef.Initialize(setting);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot access the DOM directly in a V8extension,  they're for defining functions, see the upstream documentation https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/(_globals).html#CefRegisterExtension(constCefString&,constCefString&,CefRefPtr<CefV8Handler>)

Comment: @amaitland Could you please provide a really simple working example, which let's say if current URL is foo.com then redirects to bar.com using CefSharp extension?

Comment: Extension support is very limited.There's absolutely no need for an extension to perform a redirect.  http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IResourceRequestHandler_OnBeforeResourceLoad.htm inherit from http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/Methods_T_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler.htm and only override the method you need. Then assign to ChromiumWebBrowser ResourceHandler property.

Comment: We want to use extensions for calculating idle time on a specific page/url and redirect to another page after. do you think that cefsharp can do this for us or we should use an alternative solution?

Comment: `CefSharp` is just one of many `Chromium Embedded Framework` wrappers. It's extension support is very limited as I've said, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions You can load `chrome://extensions-support` in the browser to see which extensions are currently supported. Personally I wouldn't bother, just inject some javascript into each page load.