# Is there an alternative to headless Chrome to use Extensions?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless, cefsharp.offscreen

I’m trying to make a selenium automation that needs to run multiple Chrome windows at the same time. I attempted using Chrome in headless mode, but since it doesn’t support installing extensions, I need an alternative. So my question is: is there another way to run Chrome without the actual window enabling the use of Extensions?

Comment: Check out cefsharp, sounds limied on extensions as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334116/how-to-load-an-extension-in-a-cefsharp-wpf-project

Comment: It has a headless type which is cefsharp.offscreen

Answer (score 3):

Extensions aren't supported in [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension error loading an extension to Chrome Headless using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344970/unknown-error-failed-to-wait-for-extension-background-page-to-load-chrome-exte/62346996#62346996)

Apparently, it seems to be supported by *headless* [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox)